# Finding rows with date between two days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to retrieve the rows from oracle db for which date is in between two particular dates.

```
FIRST_ACTIVE_TS
---------------
17-11-07
17-11-07
```

Query that i am using :

```
select first_active_ts from <Table name> where TRUNC(first_active_ts) 
between TO_DATE('2017-11-06','YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE('2017-11-08','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But the query returns 0 rows.

Comment: are you using TRUNC correctly?

Comment: What about this `SELECT first_active_ts
  FROM <Table name> 
  where TO_DATE(first_active_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
between TO_DATE('2017-11-06','YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE('2017-11-08','YYYY-MM-DD');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select first_active_ts
from   <Table name>
where  first_active_ts >= DATE '2017-11-06'                     -- Start date
AND    first_active_ts <  DATE '2017-11-08' + INTERVAL '1' DAY; -- End date+1 day
```

> But the query returns 0 rows.

Your dates are showing in `RR-MM-DD` format. Use `TO_CHAR( first_active_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )` to display them and you might find that the year has been mistakenly entered as `0017` rather than `2017`. If this is the case then the query is correctly returning zero rows and you will need to fix your data.

Comment: actually partially you got it right. when i printed using char it showed "0007-11-17". so its basically dont know why taking date as 0007 instead of 07.

Comment: @SrijanSharma You have a `DD-MM-YYYY` input and users have been entering `17-11-07` and to the database `07` means `7 AD` not `2007 AD` and you get the wrong year. You need to enforce that the valid dates are entered (either with a constraint on the database or by updating the UI where the dates are entered to make it more obvious the full year is needed - or both).

Comment: thanks mate for figuring out the problem. was stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FIRST_ACTIVE_TS FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE  FIRST_ACTIVE_TS BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('2017-11-06','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2017-11-08','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: This will not get rows where the date is between `2017-11-08 00:00:01` and `2017-11-08 23:59:59`

Comment: I have tried this script worked correctly.I have tested in oracle 11g.